# SSIS parameterized datasource from SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, ssis

This is what I have been trying to do:

SSIS package : Items

[image]

With the following sql statement, using linked server:

```
USE [TARGET]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Item]
       ([No_]
       ,[Description]
       ,[Unit Price]
       )
SELECT [No_]
      ,[Description]
      ,[Unit Price]
FROM [SOURCE].[Database].[dbo].[Item]
```

[image]

What I want to do:

[image]

Store the datasource for both TARGET and SOURCE in sql table Datasource:

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TARGET;Provider=SQLNCLI.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;

Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=SOURCE;Provider=SQLNCLI.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;
```

And finally update the sql statement in the SSIS package pointing at a parameter.

```
INSERT INTO @SOURCE +'.[Item]'+
       ([No_]
       ,[Description]
       ,[Unit Price]
       )
SELECT [No_]
      ,[Description]
      ,[Unit Price]
FROM @SOURCE +'.[Item]'+
```

But not been successful so far, any suggestions?

---

Update:

Was missing one picture:

[image]

In the connection manager I would want to get the datasource information from the table Datasource (first picture after "what I want to do")

---

Update 2:

Is this possible??

[image]

Comment: I have voted to close this as it is unclear. The pictures are nice but you need to elaborate on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this in `Execute SQL Task`:-

```
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) 
DECLARE @TARGET nvarchar(200) = ?
DECLARE @SOURCE nvarchar(200) = ?
Set  @query ='INSERT INTO ' + @TARGET +'.[Item]
   ([No_]
   ,[Description]
   ,[Unit Price]
   )
   SELECT [No_]
  ,[Description]
  ,[Unit Price]
  FROM ' +  @SOURCE +'.[Item]'
EXEC(@query)
```

In the `Parameter Mapping` map the `?` to the variables created ie Target and Source

Comment: OK looks good. I´m having problems adding the datasource for the linked server information... (added a picture)

Comment: U can select any database while creating a connection becase you will always access the Linked tables using `[Server].[Database].[Schema].[Table]`